# how do I escape ' in sed?

Tags: sed, sh

I do not understand what I am doing wrong here:

```
$ cat fixnames.sh
#!/bin/sh

for i in *mp3
do
    j=`echo $i | sed -e's/ /_/g'`
    j=`echo $j | sed -e's/_(...)_/_/g'`
    j=`echo $j | sed -e's/\'//g'`
    echo $j
done
$ ./fixnames.sh
./fixnames.sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

I guess the line `/bin/sh` does not like is ...

```
j=`echo $j | sed -e's/\'//g'`
```

... so how am I suppose to remove `'` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's shell not `sed` giving trouble.  You can't escape single quotes in a single-quoted string.

```
for i in *mp3
do
    j=$(echo $i | sed -e 's/ /_/g' -e 's/_(...)_/_/g' -e "s/'//g")
    echo $j
done
```

In this context, it is sufficient to use double quotes around the expression.  Other times, you need to be more careful with the double quotes (stray `$` need escaping, etc), or you use the canonical sequence `'\''` to embed a single quote in a single quoted string:

```
-e 's/'\''//g'
```

The `'\''` sequence stops the current single quoted string, inserts an escaped single quote (effectively just a single quote), and resumes the single quoted string.

Note that I combined the 3 invocations of `sed` into one; I like the `-e` option but many people would use semicolons to separate the three commands.  Also note the use of `$(...)` in preference to back-quotes.